# Creating new records with comma delimited values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in worksheet1 where one column "G" allows multiple values that are separated by comma, e.g. 12,24,72. In worksheet2, I want to read the table or worksheet1 and write new records (rows) with select columns C & G. If a comma is identified in G, worksheet1 I would like to have it create a new row for each instance in worksheet2.

Worksheet1

```
ID(A) | Name(C) | Period(G)
1     | Paul    | 12
2     | Sam     | 12,14,72
3     | Karen   | 36
```

Worksheet2

```
Paul  | 12
Sam   | 12
Sam   | 14
Sam   | 72
Karen | 36
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide the code you already have and exactly where you got stuck with it. Make it specific. Right now this question is too broad: it sounds too much like "please write the code for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code (comments are in code):

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillWS()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    ' Set references to worksheets
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Worksheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Worksheet2")
    ' Determine last row in column C in worksheet1
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, currentRow As Long, name As String, period() As String
    currentRow = 1
    ' Loop through first worksheet
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        name = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        period = Split(ws1.Cells(i, 7).Value, ",")
        For j = LBound(period) To UBound(period)
            ws2.Cells(currentRow, 1) = name
            ws2.Cells(currentRow, 2) = period(j)
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Pablo If it helped, you should mark it as accepted (green check mark on the left side).